# How to code "Restart Kernel and Run all" in button for Python Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, widget, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create a GUI in Jupyter notebook using python. I have coded the buttons to execute the code using widgets. But I'm running into two issues:

1. Code a snippet to restart kernel and run all cells (rs_button in the code snippet below)
2. Less important: Is there anyway I can hide all the codes in python and just keep the buttons as well as user input cells on display?

Here's what I've been trying:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
rs_button = widgets.Button(description="Restart Kernel!")
exec_button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
display(rs_button,exec_button)

def rs_button_clicked(b):
    IPython.notebook.execute_cell();


def exec_button_clicked(b):
    import data_assess_v6 as data_profiler
    (execution_time) = data_profiler.data_profile(path,file)

rs_button.on_click(rs_button_clicked)
exec_button.on_click(exec_button_clicked)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I have been able to achieve these 2 functionalities by injecting javascript into the notebook. Below is the code snippet.

```
from IPython.display import HTML, Javascript, display

def initialize():
    display(HTML(
        '''
            <script>
                code_show = false;
                function restart_run_all(){
                    IPython.notebook.kernel.restart();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        IPython.notebook.execute_all_cells();
                    }, 10000)
                }
                function code_toggle() {
                    if (code_show) {
                        $('div.input').hide(200);
                    } else {
                        $('div.input').show(200);
                    }
                    code_show = !code_show
                }
            </script>
            <button onclick="code_toggle()">Click to toggle</button>
            <button onclick="restart_run_all()">Click to Restart and Run all Cells</button>
        '''
    ))
initialize()
```

The `restart_run_all()` function restarts the notebook kernel and then executes all cells after 10 seconds. The parameter to the timeout function can be adjusted as necessary.

The `code_toggle()` function toggles the input areas of the cells in the notebook. It also gives a nice animation while toggling the code cells.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, you can give try out the `voila` project:
https://github.com/QuantStack/voila

It does exactly what you are asking for!

Hope this helps.

Edit:

After you install the `voila` package (either through pip or conda), on a terminal write

`voila Notebook.ipynb`

where Notebook.ipynb is your Jupyter notebook that you'd like to run. All the cells of that notebook will be executed as in a standard kernel, but only the output will be shown.

For more info, please refer to the link above.

Comment: Please add some more details in your answer instead of copying a link.

Comment: Voilà seems to be a very great package but how to implement the first question with voilà ?

How to be able to re-execute all cells from the voilà interface ? This is very important if results have to be refreshed each day and can help many of us I think