# Jupyter Notebook Restart and Run All Cells Automatically

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My code connects with a database and sometimes the database disconnects on me. As result the script ends. I would like to be able to add a line of code that would allow me to restart and run all the cells in Jupyter notebook.

Input:

```
if condition ==True:
   #Kernel restart and run all jupyter cells
```

I understand there is already a question that may seem similar but it is not. It only creates a button that you can click to restart and run all the cell

[How to code "Restart Kernel and Run all" in button for Python Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886701/how-to-code-restart-kernel-and-run-all-in-button-for-python-jupyter-notebook)

Thank you

Comment: Why not refresh the connection instead?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. You can make the kernel exit, but then that's that. You've exited the kernel, there's nothing to "rerun" the code. You could wrap all of your code in a function and rerun the function, which is easier. The best thing to do would be to refresh the db connection. When it disconnects, handle that by re-instantiating the database connection. If it's a constant problem, you may need to adjust the timeout on your connection or look into connection pooling

Answer (score 0):

Would a keyboard shortcut suffice?

For JupyterLab users and those using the document-centric notebook experience in the future, see [How to save a lot of time by have a short cut to Restart Kernel and Run All Cells?](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-save-a-lot-of-time-by-have-a-short-cut-to-restart-kernel-and-run-all-cells/11756/2?u=fomightez).

---

For those still using the classic notebook (version 6 and earlier) interface to run Jupyter notebooks:
A lot of the classic notebook 'tricks' will cease to work with version 7 of the document-centric notebook experience (what most people not consider the 'classic notebook interface') that is on the horizon. The version 7 and forward will use tech that is currently underlying JupyterLab, see [Build Jupyter Notebook v7 off of JupyterLab components](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html). And so moving towards JupyterLab now will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code can help. However, it requires Javascript to run. So, you need to run your notebook on a **browser** instead of an IDE like Vscode.

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript

if condition:
    display(Javascript(
    """
        IPython.notebook.set_autosave_interval(0); // turn off autosave
        IPython.notebook.save_notebook(); // save the notebook before restarting
        IPython.notebook.kernel.restart();
        setTimeout(
            IPython.notebook.execute_all_cells(),
            5000
        ) // wait 5sec for restarting finished and then execute all cells
    """
    ))
```